# C++ Mask Butterworth High Pass Filter

Tags: image-processing, mask, highpass-filter, butterworth

I am looking for a C++ implementation of a mask Butterworth high pass filter.

I have an image that has been masked and I would like to apply a Butterworth high pass filter without having edge effect where the image was masked.

For now I am using vtk to filter my image.

Any piece of advice is welcome :)

Comment: Try this https://github.com/ruohoruotsi/Butterworth-Filter-Design

Comment: Thank you @aaronR. This code seems to be for sound file (1D). Do you think I can try to adapt it for 2D images ?

Comment: I am not familiar with the topic. I did a quick search to see if I could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two concepts:

### High-pass filtering

A high-pass filter can be obtained using a low-pass filter and some trivial arithmetic. For example (using generic syntax here, you didn't tag any specific language):

```
img = ... (you input image)
lowpass = smooth(img)
highpass = img - lowpass
```

*Unsolicited advice*:

I don't see the point in using a Butterworth filter. It's a brilliant design if you are limited to causal filters (as in an electronic circuit processing a signal in real time), but for images this is a pointless constraint. Use a [Gaussian filter](http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/22).

### Normalized convolution

When you are facing uncertain or incomplete data (as is the case of your masked image: the pixels masked out are considered unknown values), then normalized convolution is the way to go.

Normalized convolution is trivially implemented as follows. Here we consider `mask` to be the mask image, with values of 1 where the data is known, and values of 0 where it is not (the regions masked out are 0 in the mask):

```
out = filter(mask * img) / filter(img)
```

Here, `filter` is any linear filter (convolution), such as the Gaussian smoothing or the high-pass filter discussed above.

`out` will have information within the regions masked out. This information is extrapolated from the known data, but you might not want to trust that. You can then mask `out` again to make sure you don't use those values:

```
out = out * mask
```

Note that multiplying by mask means that the masked-out pixels are multiplied by 0, leading to a 0 output, and the other values are multiplied by 1, and thus not affected.